# python error TypeError: a bytes-like object is required,not 'str'

Tags: python, sockets

```
connectionSocket.send("%s\r\n%s\r\n\r\n" %(first_header.encode(encoding='utf_8'), following_header.encode(encoding='utf_8')))
```

[image]

Comment: Please post the rest of your code, we can't help you without having some more info

Answer (score 2):

You are still sending a `str` string object, because you used a string template (interpolating `b'...'` byte literal syntax into it).

Encode the result of the `str % (params)` operation instead:

```
data = "%s\r\n%s\r\n\r\n" % (first_header, following_header)
connectionSocket.send(data.encode(encoding='utf_8'))
```